# No assignment has given for field

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
type Client = 
      { Name : string; Income : int ; YearsInJob : int
        UsesCreditCard : bool;  CriminalRecord : bool }

type QueryInfo =
      { Title     : string
        Check     : Client -> bool
        Positive  : Decision
        Negative  : Decision }

    and Decision = 
       | Result of string
       | Querys  of QueryInfo

let tree =
       Querys  {Title = "More than €40k"
               Check = (fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000)
               Positive = moreThan40
               Negative = lessThan40}
```

But in the last line :

```
 Querys  {Title = "More than €40k"
                   Check = (fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000)
                   Positive = moreThan40
                   Negative = lessThan40}
```

I have an erorr:

```
No assignment has given for field 'Check' of type 'Script.QueryInfo'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# is **white-space sensitive**, which means that white-space is used to indicate scope. The code as given doesn't compile because `Check` appears too far to the left.

This, on the other hand, ought to compile (if `moreThan40` and `lessThan40` are correctly defined):

```
let tree =
       Querys {Title = "More than €40k"
               Check = (fun cl -> cl.Income > 40000)
               Positive = moreThan40
               Negative = lessThan40}
```

The curly brackets here do not indicate scope, but instead the start and end of a record. Because of the incorrect indentation in the OP, the compiler sees the `Check` binding as outside the scope of the record expression. That's the reason it complains that no value has been bound to the field `Check`.

Until you get used to **significant white-space**, it can be a bit annoying, but it does save you from a lot of explicit opening and closing of scopes (e.g. with curly brackets), so in my opinion, it's a benefit once you get used to it.